# Anonymous structs

Tags: c, gcc, struct, c11

I need an anonymous struct embedded within struct test so that it is set up like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    char name[20];

    struct {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
};

int main(void) {
    struct test srs = { "1234567890123456789", 0, 0 };
    printf("%d\n", srs.x); // I can access x property without having to go to go within another struct
    return 0;
}
```

So that I can access x and y properties without having to go to go within another struct.

However I would like to be able to use a struct definition which is declared elsewhere like so:

```
struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

I am not able to edit the above struct!

So, for example, some pseudo code might be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct test {
    char name[20];

    struct position;
};

int main(void) {
    struct test srs = { "1234567890123456789", 0, 0 };
    printf("%d\n", srs.x); // I can access x property without having to go to go within another struct
    return 0;
}
```

However this gives:

```
warning: declaration does not declare anything
In function 'main':
error: 'struct test' has no member named 'x'
```

UPDATE: Some commenters are wondering how to initialise such a struct, so I wrote a simple program for you to experiment with, make sure to compile with -fms-extensions as per the answer!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct test {
    char name[20];

    struct position;
};

int main(void) {
    struct test srs = { "1234567890123456789", 1, 2 };
    printf("%d\n", srs.x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 1, which you would expect.

There is no need for:

```
struct test srs = { "1234567890123456789", { 1, 2 } };
```

However if you do, it will give the same output with no warnings.

I hope this clarifies!

Comment: Can't you use pointer casts or unions, or inheritance? Your question is not very clear ...

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Rather `return 0;` to indicate success.

Comment: OK; I've changed the return value even though it isn't relevant.

Comment: @CHRIS That's why I've put it down as a comment. Another thing, with your initializer for `srs`, you are putting all that explicit zeroes to `name[0]`, 1, 2 and 3. Rest are zero, because they are implied so when not mentioned. Rather use nested braces for better results, even for your inner structure, like the following: `... = {{1}, {2, 3}};`.

Comment: My code gives no warnings when compiled with the answer flag and works perfectly.

Comment: @CHRIS I don't get it. What is the output you get with the first code you've provided, if you change your zeroes with `1, 2, 3, 4`? It should be rather a zero still. If that was what you were already after, fine. But if you were hoping to lay down an initial value for `x`, then you have many solutions for that, one of them being `... = {{set_of_values_for_name}, {value_for_x, value_for_y}};`.

Comment: I've updated the question for you with an additional bit at the bottom to clarify how to initialise the struct; even though it isn't very relevant to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per c11 standards, its possible to use anonymous structs in gcc. Using `-fms-extensions` compiler option will allow for anonymous struct features you want.

Relevant excerpt from the docs:

> Unless -fms-extensions is used, the unnamed field must be a structure
>   or union definition without a tag (for example, ‘struct { int a; };’).
>   If -fms-extensions is used, the field may also be a definition with a
>   tag such as ‘struct foo { int a; };’, a reference to a previously
>   defined structure or union such as ‘struct foo;’, or a reference to a
>   typedef name for a previously defined structure or union type.

Refer: [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define position {int x; int y;}

struct test {
    char name[20];

    struct position;
};
```

Is expanded to:

```
struct test {
    char name[20];

    struct {int x; int y;};
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately the struct is not my definition, it is from a library so I cannot alter its definition.